# Does Huawei Honor support silent camera mode in Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, camera, huawei-u8860, mute

I use the app `Camera Zoom FX` for taking photos. On Gingerbread, I was able to mute its sounds via the settings. After updating to Ice Cream Sandwich, I always hear a sound when taking a photo.

Since I updated the app too, I was wondering: Is this a bug in `Camera Zoom FX` or doesn't ICS for Huawei Honor allow to mute its camera?

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: @Penguinolog Nope, it is running standard, unrooted Huawei Honor ICS 4.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

No, your phone needs to be rooted ( as confirmed by the developers ). You may want to try Camera ICS + however which has as many features but remains silent.

Comment: Where was this confirmed? Can you link the source?